# How to query data in SharePoint from multiple lists

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have multiple SharePoint lists and want to display data from them on to a gridview control.

Please guide me.

Grace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options that I can think of:

1. [SPSiteDataQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx)
2. Set up a search scope, metadata, and then query your Scope using Enterprise Search SQL and [FullTextSqlQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.query.fulltextsqlquery.aspx)

Answer (score 11):

Your question inspired me to develop a web part that demonstrates:

1. How to query SharePoint data in the many ways offered by the API, and
2. How to bind it to a grid view.

It can be [found on CodePlex here](http://spquerydemo.codeplex.com/). Some of it is a little rough but it should be enough to show you the basics. It demonstrates the following query types:

- For loop (if that counts)
- GetListItems from Lists web service
- SPQuery for SPList objects
- SPSiteDataQuery for cross-site list queries
- CrossListQueryInfo for cached cross-site list queries
- PortalSiteMapProvider for SharePoint Server publishing sites only

There is code for using the search engine but this isn't wired up to the web part itself yet.

I hope it helps you. If you try it and have problems please use the CodePlex site to get support from me.

Comment: That's cool Alex. You always do a great job. Keep up the good work!

Comment: +1 for answering the question and providing a working demonstration that truly goes above and beyond!

Comment: @Grace Kim: Feel free to upvote this answer if it helps you! ;-)

Comment: The CodePlex site is no longer there.  Can you restore it, please?

Comment: @WinstonFassett Now republished to CodePlex. I didn't think anyone was still looking at it!

Answer (score 2):

With SharePoint 2007 you can use [CrossListQueryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.crosslistquerycache.aspx) and [CrossListQueryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.crosslistqueryinfo.aspx). [More information here](http://sharepoint.nailhead.net/2008/04/musing-on-crosslistquerycache-class.html).

Comment: Worth to note that these classes are available for MOSS installation only. For WSS use suggested SPSiteDataQuery.

Comment: That's what the question says - SharePoint 2007 not WSS 3.0.

Comment: Dude, I never knew about this class. Am i correct to state that this will use some cached data as a source, i.e. like the sitemap provider?