# Can we query and fetch data from LIST between different subsites using CAML Query.?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, caml

Have LIST created under one site, can the same LIST be used to fetch data from other site using CAML Query.?

eg:

Consider a LIST "xxx" created under SitePages/AAA/Lists/

Can i access the LIST "xxx" from other site i.e SitePages/BBB/

To Summarize, Is it possible to access the LIST across parent and child sites, vice-versa.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374137/how-to-query-data-in-sharepoint-from-multiple-lists

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. The only condition is to have the same domain (for example http://mydomain.com/SitePages/AAA/ and http://mydomain.com/SitePages/BBB/).

Then, with SharepointPlus library (http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/symbols/%24SP%28%29.list.html#.get) that is a JavaScript API that would be (if you are on the http://mydomain.com/SitePages/AAA/* site) :

```
$SP().list("ListName","http://mydomain.com/SitePages/BBB/").get({
  fields:"Title"
}, function getData(data) {
  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) console.log(data[i].getAttribute("Title"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as they are under the same site collection, you can use SPSiteDataQuery
[Link to MSDN SPSiteDataQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx)
SPSiteDataQuery allows you to set the Site collection under which to search the lists.